# What does "Range: 10/20" mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

Ranged weapons have a range which usually shows two values, for example "10/20". I'm guessing depending on something a PC (or NPC) might have a range of 10 OR 20. Sadly, I don't know what causes this range to change.

Could someone explain this duality of range stats?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The number before the slash indicates normal range.

The number after the slash indicates "long range" - when an attack is performed at long range, it takes a -2 penalty to the attack roll.

Comment: I actually found the answer after a bit of digging, but I figured I'd post it here, as it's not that obvious and might save someone some confusion later on. ;)

Comment: well done. we like it when people do this!